# How to set timeout in Kong v1.1.2

Tags: nginx, timeout, nginx-reverse-proxy, kong, request-timed-out

**Problem**

I am getting an error message in my Kong error log reporting that the upstream server has timed out. But I know that the upstream process was just taking over a minute, and when it completes (after Kong has logged the error) it logs a java error "Broken Pipe", implying that Kong was no longer listening for the response.

This is the behavior when the upstream process takes longer than 60 seconds. In some cases, it takes less than 60 seconds and everything works correctly.

**How can I extend Kong's timeout?**

**Details**

Kong Version

```
1.1.2
```

Kong's Error Message (slightly edited):

```
2019/12/06 09:57:10 [error] 1421#0: *1377 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz, server: kong, request: "POST /api/...... HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/.....", host: "xyz.xyz.com"
```

Here is the error from the upstream server log (Java / Tomcat via SpringBoot)

```
Dec 06 09:57:23 gateway-gw001-99 java[319]: org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
Dec 06 09:57:23 gateway-gw001-99 java[319]:         at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:364) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.42.jar!/
Dec 06 09:57:23 gateway-gw001-99 java[319]:         at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:833) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.42.jar!
...
```

My kong.conf (slightly edited)

```
trusted_ips = 0.0.0.0/0
admin_listen = 0.0.0.0:8001
proxy_listen = 0.0.0.0:8080 proxy_protocol,  0.0.0.0:8443 ssl proxy_protocol
database = postgres
pg_host = 127.0.0.1
pg_port = 5432
pg_user = kong
pg_password = xyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
pg_database = kong
plugins = bundled,session
real_ip_header = proxy_protocol
```

**A little more Context**

- Kong and the Upstream Server are hosted on the same Ubuntu VM
- The Ubuntu VM is hosted as a linux container (LXC) inside another Ubuntu VM
- The outer VM uses NGinX to receive public traffic and reverse proxies it to Kong. It does this using stream. This allows Kong to be my SSL demarcation point.

The Outer NGinX Stream Config:

```
stream {

    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz:8080;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz:8443;
        proxy_protocol on;
    }
}
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried adding the following lines to kong.conf. In version 1.1.2 of Kong you basically alter the NGinX settings remotely by adding prefixes to NginX config and placing them in the kong.conf (https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/configuration/#injecting-individual-nginx-directives ). None of them seemed to do anything:

```
nginx_http_keepalive_timeout=300s
nginx_proxy_proxy_read_timeout=300s
nginx_http_proxy_read_timeout=300s
nginx_proxy_send_timeout=300s
nginx_http_send_timeout=300s
```

Comment: Do you have `upstream_read_timeout` set in your kong options? https://docs.konghq.com/0.10.x/proxy/#3-proxying--upstream-timeouts

Comment: ah, how did I miss that. That's it, thanks.
respond with the answer and I'll give it to you. Yeah I just did read and write timeout in a service update: https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/admin-api/#update-service

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/0.10.x/proxy/#3-proxying--upstream-timeouts) `Kong` Version 0.10 has three properties that you can set for managing `proxy` connections

1. `upstream_connect_timeout`: defines in milliseconds the timeout for
   establishing a connection to your upstream service.
2. `upstream_send_timeout`: defines in milliseconds a timeout between two successive write operations for transmitting a request
   to your upstream service.
3. `upstream_read_timeout`:
   defines in milliseconds a timeout between two successive read
   operations for receiving a request from your upstream service.

In this case, as `Kong` is timing out waiting for the response from the upstream you would need to add a property setting for `upstream_read_timeout`

In the `Kong` Version 1.1 [documentation](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/admin-api/#add-service) the Service object now includes these timeout attributes with slightly different names:

1. `connect_timeout`: The timeout in milliseconds for establishing a connection to the upstream server. Defaults to 60000.
2. `write_timeout`: The timeout in milliseconds between two successive write operations for transmitting a request to the upstream server. Defaults to 60000.
3. `read_timeout`: The timeout in milliseconds between two successive read operations for transmitting a request to the upstream server. Defaults to 60000.

Comment: I updated the response with the Version 1.1 details that I used.

Comment: sorry, I have a question: I use Kong by configuring it with a kong.yml file; where / how should the timeouts be set in this file? can you write some examples please?
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

if you use Kubernetes, you must specify a special annotation in service:

```
konghq.com/override: {{ ingressName }}
```

no obvious, though.
I discovered it here https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/905#issuecomment-739927116

example of service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websocket
  annotations:
    konghq.com/override: timeout-kong-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    app: websocket
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8010
```

for detailed explanation please follow the link above

Comment: Please explain your answer and quote a reference.

Comment: I hope it is better now

Comment: Sure is, I have upvoted it.